# Tensorflow _lstm_ops.dll not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build an LSTM model that I downloaded from Github, using Tensorflow and Python 3.6. The link for the model is https://github.com/adeshpande3/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis.
When the following command is executed
lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstmUnits)
I am receiving the error
NotFoundError: D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops_lstm_ops.dll not found
As you may have notices, the path has no non-ASCII codes!!
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the project's [Github page](https://github.com/adeshpande3/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis), the code runs on TensorFlow 1.1, and won't work with TensorFlow 1.2 or higher. If you're using a current version of TensorFlow, that's your problem.

Comment: TensorFlow version 1.1 (Currently not supported for 1.2 but working on it) deceived me.